# Set Text style in Webdriver using Java (Color, bold or italic)

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I have this code that writes Pass or Fail in the excel sheet result column.
I wanted to make it little fancy and add aether green/red color to text or make it bold or both.

```
  DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
    sTestCaseName = this.toString();
    sTestCaseName = Utils.getTestCaseName(this.toString());
    Log.startTestCase(sTestCaseName);
    ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData + Constant.File_TestData,"Sheet1");
    iTestCaseRow = ExcelUtils.getRowContains(sTestCaseName,Constant.Col_TestCaseName);
    driver = Utils.OpenBrowser(iTestCaseRow);    

<some method here...>

//here to write Pass or Fail

    ExcelUtils.setCellData("Pass", iTestCaseRow, Constant.Col_Result);
              }catch (Exception e){
    ExcelUtils.setCellData("Fail", iTestCaseRow, Constant.Col_Result);

    Log.error(e.getMessage());
    throw (e);
```

Can you suggest how can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Excel, then the easiest and most automatic way is to use Conditional Formatting. In Excel 2010 or higher, under the Home tab, you'll find the Conditional Formatting button.

I would suggest adding two conditions, one for PASS and one for FAIL. Choose New Rule, and then use the second option from the top that read "Format only cells that contain". This option will let you specify if the cell equals a value, contains a value, does not equal a value, etc.

Once you've decided on the rule, click the "Format" button to bring up the cell format dialog box. Format each one whichever shades of green and red you want, then apply it to the range that is going to get the result. Then click Apply or OK to finish it out.

Comment: Thanks Scott, i will try that